# How to autofilter column 1 and return related results in column 2

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter

This is my first post. I am new to VBA and programming in general. I am still trying to get the hang of when to use variables and everything else. I am writing a basic VBA against a download file that can not be changed. Code is below

```
Sub KPIMacroFull()

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet1.Name)
Rows("1:2").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 9).Activate
    Range("J:J").AutoFilter 1, 20


lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
    If lr > 1 Then
        Range("A2:A" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    End If


Cells.AutoFilter
Cells.AutoFilter


ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 20).Activate


Range("AD1").EntireColumn.Insert
Range("AD1").Value = "Rush or Regular"
Range("A1:AK1").Columns.AutoFit
Range("AC:AC").AutoFilter 29, "D"
```

So basically what I want to do is autofilter column AC for values "D","K","Q","V","U",1,9.  then in Column AD excel would return "Regular". For all other values in column AC (there are about 15 more classifications) I want excel to return "Rush". I am thinking a variable to set Regular to the above values and then going from there, but I am lost.

I checked a lot of other autofilter and VBA posts, but my questions seems to be more rudimentary and have not found anything too helpful.

Comment: sorry, all parts of my code are working to my liking until the last line. that being said, suggestions on improvements to the rest are welcome, but my real question is about the last line of code.

Comment: Could you write an if statement in column AD to populate with "Regular" and "Rush"?

Comment: Thanks Kyle, I am sure that I can, logically that makes sense. Let me try a few things and if I am stumped again, I will reach out.

Comment: This should do it. Put this in cell AD1 and drag down (assuming your data starts in AC1) `=If(Or(AC1 = "D", AC1 = "K", AC1 = "Q", AC1 = "V", AC1 = "U", AC1 = "1", AC1 = "9"),"Regular","Rush")`

Comment: Thanks Kyle, and yes, that will work- but basically what i want to do is write that formula in VBA to automate the process. Some kind of boolean expression i suppose.

Comment: `Range("ad1").Formula = "=If(Or(AC1 = "D", AC1 = "K", AC1 = "Q", AC1 = "V", AC1 = "U", AC1 = "1", AC1 = "9"),"Regular","Rush")"`

`Range("ad1:ad" Range("ac" & activesheet.rows.count).end(xlup).row)).autofill`

Answer (score 0):

This sniplet is independent from your solution as that relies too much on views.
My sniplet parses through your "AC" column and does all your required fill-in.
It is time-consuming, but not as much as yours (I assume you're not working on 100,000 record datasets, more like couple-hundred line evaluations of MMOs so it really shouldn't matter).
Filtering itself is up to you, add that part to the end of my sub.

```
Sub ertdfgcvb()
LastRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
Dim RegBool As Boolean
Dim ert As String
Dim MyArray(6) As String
MyArray(0) = "D"
MyArray(1) = "K"
MyArray(2) = "Q"
MyArray(3) = "V"
MyArray(4) = "U"
MyArray(5) = "1"
MyArray(6) = "9"
For i = 1 To LastRow
    RegBool = False
    ert = CStr(Cells(i, 29).Value) 'the CStr is unnecessary
    'unless you want to make it case-insensitive, in which case
    'you'll want to wrap it in a UCase() function
    For j = 0 To 6 'size of your array
        If InStr(1, ert, MyArray(j)) <> 0 Then RegBool = True
    Next

    If RegBool Then
        Cells(i, 30) = "Regular"
    Else
        Cells(i, 30) = "Rush"
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you!! and actually I am working on 100,000 plus data set. 102,124 specifically...I am sure my code is very inefficient.

Comment: Adding "righnow = Now" to the beginning then "rightnow2 = Now" to somewhere by the end and "MsgBox(rightnow2-rightnow)" or some variations thereof can help you a great deal with optimising your runtime.